# Django data leak between 2 separated tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

In my whole tests base, I experience a weird behaviour with two tests. They are completely isolated. However, I can find data from the first test in the second one. Here are the tests:

**file1 (services.tests)**

```
class ServiceTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch('categories.models.ArticlesByCategory.objects.has_dish_type')
    def test_build_dishtype_conflicts(self, mock_has_dish_type):
        # WARN: create interference in tests
        restaurant = RestaurantFactory()
        dt_1 = DishTypeFactory(restaurant=restaurant)
        cat_1 = CategoryFactory(restaurant=restaurant)
        art_1 = ArticleFactory(name='fooA1', restaurant=restaurant)
        art_2 = ArticleFactory(name='fooA2', restaurant=restaurant)
        abc_1 = ArticlesByCategory.objects.create(category=cat_1, article=art_1, is_permanent=True,
                                              dish_type=dt_1)
        abc_2 = ArticlesByCategory.objects.create(category=cat_1, article=art_2, is_permanent=True,
                                              dish_type=dt_1)

        mock_has_dish_type.return_value = [abc_1, abc_2]
        abcs_to_check = ArticlesByCategory.objects.filter(pk__in=[abc_1.pk, abc_2.pk])
        conflicts = ServiceFactory()._build_dishtype_conflicts(abcs_to_check)
        self.assertDictEqual(conflicts, {dt_1.pk: 2})
```

**file2 (products.tests)**

```
class ArticleQuerySetTestCase(TestCase):
def test_queryset_usable_for_category(self):
    restaurant = RestaurantFactory()
    category_1 = CategoryFactory(name='fooB1', restaurant=restaurant)
    category_2 = CategoryFactory(name='fooB2', restaurant=restaurant)
    article_1 = ArticleFactory(restaurant=restaurant)
    article_2 = ArticleFactory(restaurant=restaurant)

    ArticlesByCategory.objects.create(article=article_1, category=category_1, is_permanent=True)
    queryset_1 = Article.objects.usable_for_category(category_1)

    # This line is used for debug
    for art in Article.objects.all():
        print(art.name)
```

When running `test_build_dishtype_conflicts` *THEN* `test_queryset_usable_for_category` in the same command, here are the results of the `print` in the second test:

```
fooA1
fooA2
fooB1
fooB2
```

I suspect I did something wrong but can't find what.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the problem from Django documentation.

If your tests rely on database access such as creating or querying models, be sure to create your test classes as subclasses of django.test.TestCase rather than unittest.TestCase.

Using unittest.TestCase avoids the cost of running each test in a transaction and flushing the database, but if your tests interact with the database their behavior will vary based on the order that the test runner executes them. This can lead to unit tests that pass when run in isolation but fail when run in a suite.